# PHP - IF div clicked/has class or id return code

Tags: php

Some HTML

```
<div class='menu_mcwiki'>
     <ul>
          <li> <p> Blocks List </p></li>
          <li> <p> Item List </p></li>
          <li> <p> Potions & Food </p></li>
          <li> <p> NPC Trading </p></li>
          <li> <p> Crafting </p></li>
          <li> <p> Enchanting </p></li>
          <li> <p>Legend:</p></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to get something like, if you click on `<li>`, the if statement in php file will show an output.

I thought to do it with javascript's `.addClass` `.removeClass` for add or remove class from `<li>`, and add to a php file if statement something like `{if has class1}` then show output, and if it doesn't exist: show anything.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Sorry for my English.

Comment: You shouldn't use `<p>` tag inside `<li>` tags. I would also recommend [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) - among many other features it makes AJAX calls very easy.

Comment: So you want to catch the class (client side) in PHP (server side). This makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get something like, if you click on LI, the if statement in php file show output.

Not doable just with PHP. You need some kind of AJAX call to a webserver script to do that. JQuery might be what you are searching, which is nicely documented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quit get it, jQuery is the solution man but if you're not into it maybe you could try something like this:

```
<ul id="ulist1">
  <li>Blocks List</li>
  <li>Item List</li>
  <li>Potions & Food</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var ulist1 = document.getElementById("ulist1");
    var childs = ulist1.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i=0; i<childs.length; i++) {

      // do something with childs[i], which is a <li> element;
      // u could apply your <?php ?> here if you want also;

    }
</script>
```